# PHP HTTP Authentication if conditional statement

Tags: php, http, authentication

```
<?php
   if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
      header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
      header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
      echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
      exit;
   } else {
      echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
      echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
   }
?>
```

This piece of code kind of defies the logic behind the way an "if" control structure works. But I have seen the same thing in many pieces of code so for some reason it must be right. Yet my logic tells me otherwise.

Of course the condition of `"!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))` checks to see if this variable is set on the server. Let's say that it is not set. So the server sends a request to the client requiring HTTP Authentication `"header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');"` and let's say that I provide one that is correct. After this, somehow the `"if"` control structure skips the `" header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');"` and the echo statement and the rest of the control structure. Why is this?

Comment: Shouldn't that line come first?

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. If the variable is not set, one block of code is executed. Otherwise, another. What do you not understand about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script runs twice.

First it goes into the first block, sends the headers and the "Text to send if user hits Cancel button" text to the browser, and then stops (see the `exit`). The PHP script is terminated completely and forgets that anything has ever happened.

The control is handed to the browser, where you enter a password. (At this point, the browser already has received the cancel button text, but is prevented from showing it due to the 401 status header.) After you enter the password, the control goes back to the server and the script is executed again **from the top**, and now (having the password sent) it runs into the second part.

If you press escape instead, the browser removes the password dialog and simply displays what it already received during the first execution (the cancel button text).

You can follow this by looking into the access log of your webserver.

Comment: Hmm kind of like a loop. So in the first block the first header sends an instruction to the browser that 'basic' authentication is being used, and the second header in the first block tells the browser that the provided credentials are not correct (or non existent) and that the user must provide credentials. But even if correct ones are provided how does that prevent the 'if' statement from skipping the 'echo' statement?

Comment: @robert The entire script runs till the end. It does not stop after the `header` calls (well, it `exit`s though). PHP is a server side language communicating through the HTTP protocol. There's no interactive back and forth in HTTP, one complete request is followed by one complete response, which means PHP does not get user feedback right in the middle of its execution.

Comment: I found the exact answer I was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770885/php-authentication-beginner

Comment: You are right about the script running twice. Because the browser re-loads the page after the second header '401 Unauthorized' with the new input thus, fetching the script with new or no input and it being verified in the conditional statement again. The second time around if it's correct or set it jumps to the second block. If the user selects 'cancel' in HTTP Authenticate the browser doesn't reload the page and the script echos out the 'Text to print out if User hits Cancel'

Comment: I also found this very helpful explanation from IBM: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cicsts/v3r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.ts31.doc%2Fdfhtl%2Ftopics%2Fdfhtl2a.htm

Comment: The key that finally made this clear to me is the following phrase, "If a client makes a request for which the server expects authentication information, the server sends an HTTP response with a 401 status code, a reason phrase indicating an authentication error, and a WWW-Authenticate header. Most Web clients handle this response by requesting a user ID and password from the end user and re-sending the original request with an Authorization header."